# AS3 - Button Click + Number

Tags: java, actionscript-3

What I'm trying to do is create a very basic button click game much like "AdVenture Capitalist" and several other casual games like it. Nothing quite as fancy. I'm using FlashDevelop (AS3) and I'm trying to figure out how to create a button then every time that button is pressed it adds +1 to my main value represented on screen.

I'd also like to figure out how to make a button that would automate the clicking process.
If anyone could show me how, or direct me to a specific page that would help me out I would be very thankful.

I'm also not sure if Actionscript is the best language to write this in. If you have a recommendation that I can use FlashDevelop with I would appreciate the tip!

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to combine `actionscript` with java or you just want to develop that game in `java`??

Comment: I'd like to combine the two if possible. Right now I'm slowly learning actionscript because FlashDevelop is set up for it.

Comment: So u just want to show how much clicks user have done till now that's it.

Comment: Yes, eventually I'd like to automate the clicking for a price and add multipliers and additional buttons, for now I'm just learning how to make the button and increase the number.

If you search www.Kongregate.com for "Adventure Capitalist" it's pretty spot on to what I'm working toward. Just a very basic version.

Comment: What exactly is your reasoning for combining this project with java? It seems really unnecessary. I think the best advice anyone can give you is to actually learn AS3(or java...?) through tutorials. A simple google search will give you dozens, if not hundreds, of resources.

Comment: I haven't combined it with Java yet. I'm currently only using AS3 for this project. I stated that I would eventually want to learn and possibly add to this project with the new knowledge.

I can't find anything specific to creating a button then once I click it, gives me a number and continues as I continue to click. I've searched quite a bit and done a few tutorials. Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: @DodgerThud according to me building GUI in java is quit hectic as compared to AS3, now a days programmers want to build GUI in very less time so there is possible tools available to combine Flash and  Java. For more detail please check the link I've given.

Comment: @VighaneshGursale seems reasonable and useful if you put it like that. thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: @VighaneshGursale I'm currently using FlashDevelop as my platform for creating code and writing. What do you use?

Comment: @Latteralus please check the link that I have posted in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have idea about the how this operation will be performed in java. For example creating buttons and labels. As long as you need to combine java and flash this [link](http://blogs.infosupport.com/flash-builder-4-the-easiest-way-to-create-a-combined-flex-java-project/) is useful for starters. If you need only java the following snippet will be useful. Also learn java swing from [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for GUI purpose

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class ButtonClick
{
    int counter = 0;
    public ButtonClick()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
        JButton btn = new JButton("Click me");
        JLabel clicks = new JLabel("");

        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                counter++;
                clicks.setText("Number of clicks till now :"+Integer.toString(counter));
                frame.repaint();
            }
        });
        frame.add(btn);
        frame.add(clicks);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        ButtonClick c = new ButtonClick();
    }
}
```